# De Rham cohomology of $S^2\setminus \{k~\text{points}\}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds

Am I right that de Rham cohomology $H^k(S^2\setminus \{k~\text{points}\})$ of $2-$dimensional sphere without $k$ points are
$$H^0 = \mathbb{R}$$
$$H^2 = \mathbb{R}^{N}$$
$$H^1 = \mathbb{R}^{N+k-1}?$$

I received this using Mayer–Vietoris sequence. And I want only to verify my result.

If you know some elementery methods to compute cohomology of this manifold, I am grateful to you.

**Calculation:**

Let's $M = S^2$, $U_1$ - set consists of $k$ $2-$dimensional disks without boundary and $U_2 = S^2\setminus \{k~\text{points}\}$.
$$M = U_1 \cup U_2$$
each punctured point of $U_2$ covered by disk (which contain in $U_1$).
And
$$U_1\cap U_2$$
is a set consists of $k$ punctured disks (which homotopic to $S^1$). Than
collection of dimensions in Mayer–Vietoris sequence
$$0\to H^0(M)\to\ldots\to H^2(U_1 \cap U_2)\to 0$$
is
$$0~~~~~1~~~~~k+\alpha~~~~~k~~~~~0~~~~~\beta~~~~~k~~~~~1~~~~~\gamma~~~~~0~~~~~0$$
whrer $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are dimensions of $0-$th, $1-$th and $2-$th cohomolody respectively.
$$1 - (k+\alpha) + k = 0,$$
so
$$\alpha = 1.$$
$$\beta - k + 1 - \gamma = 0,$$
so
$$\beta = \gamma + (k-1).$$
So
$$H^0 = \mathbb{R}$$
$$H^2 = \mathbb{R}^{N}$$
$$H^1 = \mathbb{R}^{N+k-1}$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mariano is right, your result is not correct.  Could you outline your calculation, so we can help find where you went wrong?

Comment: @you: it may take some time

Comment: @you: I have done

Comment: What is $N{}{}$? (Your result is correct for exactly *one* value of $N$ :) )

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: I need $H^{*}(S^{n}\setminus\{k~\text{points}\})$ to calculate the cohomology of sphere with $k$ handles. It is enough to satisfy the equality $\dim H^{1}(S^{n}\setminus\{k~\text{points}\}) - \dim H^{2}(S^{n}\setminus\{k~\text{points}\}) = k-1$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: but from Mayer–Vietoris sequence $\ldots\to\mathbb{R}^{1}\to\mathbb{R}^{\gamma}\to\mathbb{R}^{0}\to\ldots$ clear that $\gamma = 0$ or $1$

Comment: Actually computing the cohomology of a sphere minus a finite set is an exercise you should really complete at some point!

Comment: I'm considering computing $\mathop C\limits^\vee ech-Cohomology$ of $S^2\setminus \{k~\text{points}\}$.Then by the isomorphism between de Rham Cohomology and Cech Cohomology,we could get the de Rham Cohomology of $S^2\setminus \{k~\text{points}\}$. But how to find a good cover of it?For example,find a good cover of $S^2$-2 points.

Comment: @Aspirin: also, you probably need to know that $N$ is *finite* for that to work, no?

Answer (score 5):

Your result isn't correct.

I won't tell you the result so that you can compute it yourself, though :) There are very few things more rewarding than getting these things right oneself!

(By the way: do it for $k=1$, $2$, and $3$... you'll catch the pattern soon)

Comment: is it true, that $U_1$ and $U_2$ from Mayer–Vietoris sequence may be not connecting?

Comment: What do you mean by *not connecting*?

Comment: I corrected my question, can you verify?

Comment: Mariano, I mean not connected

Comment: @Aspirin: Sure they can.

Answer (score 2):

It helps to use the fact that DeRahm cohomology is a homotopy invariant, meaning we can reduce the problem to a simpler space with the same homotopy type.  I think the method you are trying will work if you can straighten out the details, but if you're still having trouble then try this:

$S^2$ with $1$ point removed is homeomorphic to the disk $D^2$.  If we let $S_k$ denote $S^2$ with $k$ points removed, then $S_k$ is homeomorphic to $D_{k-1}$ (where $D_{k-1}$ denotes $D^2$ with $k-1$ interior points removed).

Hint: Find a nicer space which is homotopy equivalent to $D_{k-1}$.  Can you, for instance, make it $1$-dimensional?  If you could, that would immediately tell you something about $H^2(S_k)$.  If you get that far and know Mayer-Vietoris, you should be able to work out the calculation.